Inserting data into Azure SQL using Azure functions V2 Python (Managed Identity)
I'm following the guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-add-output-binding-azure-sql-vs-code?pivots=programming-language-python,
I can get the Azure Function to deploy however it will not add the data to the SQL database, which has an Azure managed identity associated with it.
function_app.py
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import uuid
from azure.functions.decorators.core import DataType

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.function_name(name="HttpTrigger1")
@app.route(route="hello", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
@app.generic_output_binding(arg_name="toDoItems", type="sql", CommandText="dbo.ToDo", ConnectionStringSetting="Server=X.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Default; Database=X;", data_type=DataType.STRING)
def test_function(req: func.HttpRequest, toDoItems: func.Out[func.SqlRow]) -> func.HttpResponse:
     logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
     name = req.params.get('name')
     if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

     if name:
        toDoItems.set(func.SqlRow({"id": uuid.uuid4(), "title": name, "completed": "false", "url": "www"}))
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {name}!")
     else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
                    "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body",
                    status_code=400
                )

host.json

{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}


I have used the following steps for SQL output binding to work in python V2 function and here I am using ADO.NET (Microsoft Entra passwordless authentication) SQL credentials by enabling managed identity in function app.

I have made few modification in the code and it worked for me.

import azure.functions as func
import logging
from azure.functions.decorators.core import DataType
import uuid

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.function_name(name="HttpTrigger1")
@app.route(route="hello", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
@app.generic_output_binding(arg_name="toDoItems", type="sql", CommandText="dbo.ToDo", ConnectionStringSetting="SqlConnectionString",
    data_type=DataType.STRING)
def test_function(req: func.HttpRequest, toDoItems: func.Out[func.SqlRow]) -> func.HttpResponse:
     logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
     name = req.params.get('name')
     if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

     if name:
        item_id = str(uuid.uuid4())  # Convert UUID to string
        toDoItems.set(func.SqlRow({"id": item_id, "title": name, "completed": False, "url": "www"}))
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {name}!")
     else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
                    "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body",
                    status_code=400
                )


I have added the connection string in local settings file.

{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "SqlConnectionString": "Server=tcp:{serverName}.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog={DatabaseName};Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication=Active Directory Default;"
  }
}


Please make sure to use the correct connection string or else you can also copy and paste it from below



I am able to insert the rows in the database when executing the function locally.




Please note, I have added the local client Ip address in the firewall rules by navigating to Server -> Networking for local development.


I have added AzureWebJobsFeatureFlagsthe and SqlConnectionString in app settings as shown below-



Then, I deployed the function to the function app and it got deployed successfully.



To allow the function app to access the database, you need to enable below exception in the server.



Then I enabled Managed Identity in function app.



I executed the below script in the database in order to grant permission to the managed identity.

CREATE USER [managed_identity_name] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [managed_identity_name];
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [managed_identity_name];
ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER [managed_identity_name];
GO


After performing 4-6 steps, you can execute the function successfully in function app.




Thanks Afrin, that worked for me. I also had to add AZURE_CLIENT_ID to the config settings, maybe that is because it is a user defined managed Id?
